# Small issue with validating a binary tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, compiler-warnings, binary-search-tree

I wrote this recursive function, which works as expected. It validates a binary tree i.e., it checks whether the given binary tree is a binary search tree or not and gives the correct answer too.

However, I get a compiler warning saying:

```
Control may reach end of non-void function
```

I do know what this error means: the function should return a `bool` and not just fall off at the end of the function. I just don't know how to overcome it as it does return a `bool`.

I tried to search for something I might have overlooked while recursing but to no avail.

```
bool isBSTRecursively(Node * root){
    if (!root) {
        return true;
    }else if (!root->getLeft() && !root->getRight()){
        return true;
    }else if(!root->getLeft()){
        if (root->getRight()->getData() > root->getData()) {
            return isBSTRecursively(root->getRight());
        }
    }else if (!root->getRight()){
        if (root->getLeft()->getData() < root->getData()) {
            return isBSTRecursively(root->getLeft());
        }
    }else{
        return (isBSTRecursively(root->getLeft()) && isBSTRecursively(root->getRight()));
    }
}
```

Comment: How about non-unique data? I mean, a node and either of its two children (or both) may have the same data as in the node and that wouldn't violate sortedness of the tree. Does your code handle this case?

Comment: Also, what about loops, making your tree a graph? You want to check that too?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, you are right. Thank you for bringing it to my attention. I will try to incorporate those conditions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these parts:

```
}else if(!root->getLeft()){
    if (root->getRight()->getData() > root->getData()) {
        return isBSTRecursively(root->getRight());
    }
}else if (!root->getRight()){
    if (root->getLeft()->getData() < root->getData()) {
        return isBSTRecursively(root->getLeft());
    }
```

Notice that you only return in two certain cases here? That's what the warning tells you, that there are paths that the code can take that doesn't explicitly contain a `return` with a value. This can lead to weird problems if you come across a case when you code doesn't do this explicit `return`.

The easiest way to silence the warning is to add a `return false` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

you wrote a function that return true on all true options but there is no return false.

it looks like return false at the end will be correct result as well as fix the warning.